# How to overwrite file locked by QuickLook

Tags: macos

On OSX, some applications can overwrite files that QuickLook is keeping a lock on.

For example, open a Finder window and select a video file; then process a video with Handbrake and overwrite the same file. After confirming the file dialog asking permission to overwrite, the file is written.

If I try to `fopen()` a file selected in a Finder window then it fails. What is the legal mechanism for clearing "weak" locks like this ?

Answer (score 0):

`qlmanage -r` will force QuickLook to reload it's file list.